# Can PA be acyclically complete?

Tags: lo.logic, theories-of-arithmetic

Any formula $\phi$ in the first order language of arithmetic is to be called *acyclic* if and only if we can associate with it an acyclic undirected graph whose nodes are the variable symbols occurring in the formula and each edge between any two nodes of it is an atomic formula with its nodes being variables occurring in it across the sole primitive relation symbol of it. So, there is an edge between $x$ and $y$ in formulas $x < y\ ;\ S(y)=x\ ; \ x+z=y\ ;\ x \times z < y\ ; etc...$, but not necessarily between $x$ and $z$.

My question:

> Are all known examples of sentences that are undecidable in $\sf PA$ cyclic? I think the famous examples of incompleteness like the Gödel sentence, the Rosser sentence, Paris–Harrington theorem, Kirby-Paris theorem, all use cyclic formulation. I also think $\sf Con(PA)$ may be cyclic but I'm not sure.

> If those are all cyclic, then is it possible to have $\sf PA$ being complete for acyclic sentences. Whereby a sentence I mean fully quantified sentence in the language of $\sf PA$, i.e. defined symbols are not allowed!

Comment: I'm confused by your requirement for the associated graph. If my formula is just $\exists x \exists y \exists z (x+z = y)$, do there need to be any edges attached to the node associated to $z$?

Comment: @JamesHanson, for this formula you have two edges one between x and y, the other between z and y.

Comment: Are you allowing complicated terms? By Matiyasevich's theorem, there are sentences of the form $\exists x_1 \dots \exists x_n (p(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0)$ (where $p$ is a polynomial) which are independent of PA. Would these be acyclic?

Comment: @JamesHanson, No, defined terms are generally not allowed unless there is a proof that they won't break acyclicity, that is, their open expansions in the language of arithmetic is acyclic. The full open expansion must go down to atomic formulas containing no complex terms.